What is Grothendieck's subsheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ with $\mathcal{F}_0 = \{0\}$ and $\mathcal{F}_x = \mathbb{Z}$ else?
Let $\newcommand{\cO}{\mathcal{O}}(X, \cO_X)$ be a ringed space. In EGA 1, Chapter 0, item 5.1.1 Grothendieck defines what it means for an $\cO_X$-module $\newcommand{\cF}{\mathcal{F}}\cF$ to be generated by a family of global sections $(s_i)_{i \in I}$ where $s_i \in \Gamma(X, \cF)$ for all $i \in I$ and $I$ is some index set. Namely, each such $s_i$ corresponds to a morphism $\cO_X \to \cF$ and we ask the map $$
    \bigoplus_{i \in I} \cO_X \to \cF
$$
induced by the $s_i$ to be surjective.
He then goes on to note that $\cF$ can be such that there exists a point $x_0 \in X$ for which the restriction $\cF|_U$ is note generated by its sections over $U$ for any open neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$, and gives the following example: Let $X = \mathbb{R}$, $\cO_X = \underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ the constant $\mathbb{Z}$-valued sheaf on $\mathbb{R}$, and $\cF$ the subsheaf of $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ such that $\cF_0 = \{0\}$ and $\cF_x = \mathbb{Z}$ for $x \neq 0$. He then claims that $\Gamma(U, \cF|_U) = \{0\}$ for any neighborhood $U$ of $x_0 = 0$.
I'm having trouble understanding what sheaf $\cF$ is supposed to be, exactly. The first thing that comes to mind is to put $\cF(V) = \{0\}$ if $0 \in V$ and $\cF(V) = \underline{\mathbb{Z}}(V)$ else, but this does not yield a sheaf: For instance, $\cF((-3, -2) \cup (-1, 1)) = \{0\}$ which is not $\cF((-3, -2)) \times \cF((-1, 1)) \cong \mathbb{Z} \times \{0\} \cong \mathbb{Z}$. But $\cF$ is a presheaf, so are we supposed to take its sheafification?
The only other thing that comes to mind is to only declare $\cF(V) = \{0\}$ if $V$ is a connected open neighborhood of 0, which I believe should yield a sheaf (although I admit to not having checked the details since I think this interpretation is rather unlikely), but then the claim about $\Gamma(U, \cF|_U) = \{0\}$ only holds for connected $U$.
I'd thus like to ask what $\cF$ is supposed to be.

P. S. Perhaps this comes down to the fact that EGA does not seem to contain a definition of sub-sheaf (or if it does, I at least have not been able to find it). I'm thus left assuming that it means "sub-presheaf which is a sheaf," but maybe this is wrong?

Yes, if you take the sheafification of your first $\mathcal{F}$ (without the connectedness property) you get a subsheaf of  $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ with the same stalks that your presheaf

BTW, this sheaf is called the extension by zero, and if $j:U\to X$ is the open inclusion, it is denoted $j_!\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_U$.

Both of your interpretations give the same sheaf and it is the correct sheaf but lets first define what a subsheaf is. The easiest way to define a subsheaf of $\mathcal{F}$ is just as an injective map of sheaves $\mathcal{G} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ which is the same as a choice of subgroup
$$ \mathcal{G}(U) \subseteq \mathcal{F}(U) $$
for each open $U$ (that is compatible with the restriction maps).
Now we can define the sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ as "the subsheaf of $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}$ such that $\mathcal{F}_0 = 0$" more formally as follows
$$ \mathcal{F}(U) := \{s \in \underline{\mathbb{Z}}(U) | s_0 = 0 \} $$
If $U$ contains $0$ then a section $s$ of $\mathcal{F}(U)$ must be $0$ on the connected component of $0$ and is unrestricted elsewhere. So for example $\mathcal{F}((−3,−2)×(−1,1)) = \mathbb{Z}$. I believe this is the sheaf you are describing in your second interpretation.
For your first interpretation, lets call the presheaf you define $\mathcal{G}$. We have a map of presheaves $\mathcal{G} \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ so this induces a map $\mathcal{G}^+ \rightarrow \mathcal{F}$ where $\mathcal{G}^+$ is the sheafification. Since sheafification does not change the stalks, it is not hard to check that this map induces an isomorphism on the stalks and is therefore an isomorphism.
Also as Roland notes in the comments, this is the sheaf $j_! \underline{\mathbb{Z}}_{|U}$ which you can find in Hartshorne II Ex.1.19.

...so the claim that $\Gamma(U, \mathcal{F}|_U) = 0$ holds only for connected neighborhoods of the origin and is false for disconnected ones? I think this is the major thing I'm caught up on here.
